# Reading in voltages using RS485

Tags: circuits

I have a breadboard with two RS485 modules hooked up, an Arduino Uno R3 and a Raspberry Pi 3 module. We are trying to read in voltages from the RS485 but we are unsure of how to do that using the supplies we have. Is this possible to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless you are doing a quasi-485 tty ish communication, you will need additional hardware to convert voltages to and from bus levels and 5V(Arduino)/3V(pi).  what power supplies do you have and what might a conversation between the devices look like?

Comment: Sorry, but not a slightest idea what are the voltages you want to read. RS485 is a physical method to transfer a logical states between devices. If the problematic voltages are the signals in your RS485 lines get an oscilloscope. If you are going to use data communication along RS485 lines to transfer some remotely measured voltages to the computer program you need quite a complex (but probably easy to get and use IF you are a competent programmer) bunch software placed between the remote voltage metering software in the voltage meter and the computer application program. Be more specific!